Nodemailer queryA ETIMEOUT with AWS SES
So I am confused as my code works; as it does send about 100+ emails before it produces the following error:
Error: queryA ETIMEOUT email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (node:dns:213:19) {
  errno: undefined,
  code: 'EDNS',
  syscall: 'queryA',
  hostname: 'email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
  command: 'CONN'
}

Below is my code:
const transporter = createTransport({
    host: "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
        user: "xxxx", 
        pass: "BGvzGfk+",
    },
});


async function processLineByLine() {

    const fileStream = fs.createReadStream('.../emailList.txt');

    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: fileStream,
        crlfDelay: Infinity
    });

    for await (const line of rl) {

        var mailOptions = {
            from: `${from}`,
            to: `${line}`,
            subject: `${subject}`,
            html: { path: '.../Invite_Email_Template.html' }
        };
            
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
    
            if (error) {
    
                console.log(error);

            } else {

                console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
    
            }

        });

    }
    
}

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!
